# Azure Stream Analytics: SQL Output not working

Tags: output, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

**Context**

I use an Azure Stream Analytics Job to process streaming data and output the results to a SQL table. The user I use has the **db_datawriter** role assigned on the Azure SQL DB.

**Issue**

There is no output to the SQL DB Table. I also tested the query together with a Blob output (what is working well) as well as checked all columns for having the right data types and order. Also the connection tests are successful and no errors are shown in the Activity Log.

**Question**

Why is then no output generated for the SQL output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a lack of permissions. When I additionally assign the

> db_datareader

role to the user it works fine.